# How to get current balance of a user in Cyclos 3.7.3?

Tags: java

I want to know how to get the current balance of a user in Cyclos 3.7.3 in Java. I came across the code in php which didn't help me in this scenario. The code which I tried is as follows:-

```
AccountServiceImpl acc_service=new AccountServiceImpl();
User user=new UserDAOImpl().load("test",null);
        System.out.println(user);
        Member member=new Member();
        member.setUser(user);
        List<Account> list5=(List<Account>) acc_service.getAccounts(member, null);
```

But it is giving me NullPointerException. I think this approach is not correct. Please tell me how can I find the current balance and invoice for a particular user in 3.7.3 version of Cyclos in java. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Use the searchAccountHistory() method on the accounts service. It should be able to get you the balance for the specified account. Soemthing like this should be able to do what you need.

```
   public BigDecimal getBalance(String accountNumber) throws RemoteException {
    AccountHistorySearchParameters params = new AccountHistorySearchParameters();
    params.setPrincipal(accountNumber);

    AccountHistoryResultPage accountHistory = service.searchAccountHistory(params);
    return accountHistory.getAccountStatus().getAvailableBalance();
}
```

Comment: Can I know what does "service" denote here?

Comment: I hope it's not too late. service is just a variable name that i have used to declare the accounts web service which is shipped with Cyclos